# how to make a multidimensional array correctly from string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I try to make a multidimensional array in php from my sting data. But I couldn't make it. Please help me.

My sting data is 3=>11040,2=>11160,1=>23400

Want output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 23400
            [2] => 11160
            [3] => 11040
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
<?php
$txt = "3=>11040,2=>11160,1=>23400";
$a = explode(',', $txt);
$b = [];
foreach($a as $v){
    $text = explode('=>', $v);
    $b[$text[0]] = $text[1];
}
ksort($b);
$c = array($b);
var_dump($c);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 23400
            [2] => 11160
            [3] => 11040
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is correct. But my data comes from mysql output. When putting mysql output into $txt, not working. can you give me any idea?

Comment: @ABShaman Please edit your question to show exactly what is output from mysql using `var_dump`

Comment: I solved it by changing one line like this $a = explode(',',MY OUT PUT); Now ok, Thank you very musha @JacobMulquin